# Add a label to a beer can?

Tags: uv

I'm using illustrator to design a beer can label (6.25in x 5in) and want to add the image onto the beer can. I'm new with Blender and so far i've been able to import a pre-made can, adjust the can's dimensions, and apply the label as an image texture.

I can't figure out how to add the image in the correct dimension onto the can. Currently, the image is being stretched onto the entire side of the can, which does not accurately represent how the can will look. To give you an idea, the beer is being brewed by a small craft brewery and the labels don't take up the entire can's surface.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: hello could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: Start by selecting the face with the label in edit mode, then click the UV tab at the top - this will show you the UV map. To make sure you can see the face you're working with, click the little icon in the top left that looks like 2 diagonal arrows pointing in different directions (on a slant), and then put your mouse over the 3D viewport and press Z and select material preview from the pie menu. Now when you select the face with the label on your model in edit mode, the corresponding UV section will be highlighted on the left. Rotate/scale the section (in the UV viewport) to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the label a separate object, and use the Shrinkwrap modifier to attach it to the can